# Upper case (P) or lower case (p) to denote p-values and probabilities in frequentist and Bayesian statistics

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, p-value, notation, frequentist

I am conducting a study in which I am reporting results of hypothesis tests conducted in a frequentist framework, and also some additional analyses conducted in a Bayesian framework.

Should I use upper case (capital) $P$ or lower case $p$ to denote $P$/$p$-values and Bayesian probabilities?

- "p" for both frequentist and Bayesian analyses?
- "P" for both frequentist and Bayesian analyses?
- "p" for frequentist analyses and "P" for Bayesian analyses?
- or "P" for frequentist analyses and "p" for Bayesian analyses?

Comment: What is "p" ?! You ask what notation to use for probability...?

Comment: Yes... and take notice that this could be a duplicate post...

Comment: Interesting: an upvoted question with three upvoted answers and it's not clear what it's asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value

Answer (score 5):

Notationally: $P(\cdot)$ is a functional to denote probability of events. The same notation is used when speaking of probability in a frequentist framework (e.g. probability is a frequency of events observed in infinite replications of the universe, or counterfactual probability) as in a Bayesian framework (e.g. probability is a degree of belief).

The history about $p$-values seems to date back to De Moivre in the 18th century according to Wikipedia. Pearson used the capital $P$ to denote a measure of inconsistency of an observed set of data from a hypothesis which is to be tested using a test statistic which assumes a known distribution when that hypothesis is true. Modern usage has reverted to lower case $p$ more often than not, I find, because the $p$ value is not a random variable, a type of distinction which is also somewhat antiquated in modern probability theory. I think you may find for submitting statistical research that most journals use lowercase $p$ but there may be instances of $P$, the only recommendation is to agree on one usage and be consistent.

There is no $p$ for Bayesian statistics. Bayesian testing is a controversial subject, but all agree that the $p$-value should immediately be bucked when doing a Bayesian analysis. My personal preference is to report the results of a Bayesian analysis using *credible* intervals which provide a range of plausible (believable) effects for the parameter. Bayes factors can summarize tests in a manner similar to $p$-values, but $p$-values suck, why would you use them if you're doing a Bayesian analysis?

Comment: I think $P$ goes back to Laplace at least. I suggest that Bayesians need a notation choice for ?-values if only to use when they explain why they despise them.

Comment: @NickCox You're right, that's news to me.

Comment: Another carp: de Moivre wasn't yet alive in the 16th century. I should share the story in one book that he was American, an alternative fact for people interested in the history of statistics: https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3M8XODWEUPCQU

Comment: @NickCox I've only reported a handful of Bayesian studies. My favorite way to report Bayesian results is just depicting the probability distribution of the posterior in a graphic. A close second is a credible interval. A $p$-value in a Bayesian analysis makes no account of the prior or posterior, so of what use is a Bayesian analysis?

Comment: Indeed; you don't need a notation for something if you never use or discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

I favour $P$ for P-value partly because that usage goes back a long way and I like history of ideas, but perhaps more because $p$ is already overloaded: I often want $p$ to mean

1. probability in general
2. a particular probability (e.g. in notation for binomial distributions)
3. the number of predictors or covariates.

Contrary to that, a reminder or two in text that we are discussing p-values might reduce the ambiguity or puzzlement about what $p$ means.

I've not picked up any hint that being frequentist or Bayesian makes any difference to preferred notation, but that's just an uninformative prior speaking. Evidence and argument on that detail is especially welcome.

Notation in statistics (as generally in any subject with mathematical content) is a messy mixture of tradition, accident and logic. We have some guidelines, such as Greek for parameters and roman for statistics, but consistency is elusive. In directional statistics, for example, trigonometric conventions dominate and $\theta$ and $\phi$ are routinely names for variables.

We would all benefit by agreeing on some better and more consistent notations: there is just the small detail of what those might be.

Here is a case of two common notations. It would usually be futile to try to change anybody else's choice. At most we can carp if authors aren't consistent within publications we review or don't follow an arbitrary style standard for a journal.

Comment: I like some points in this answer but I hesitate to upvote because I distinctly prefer lower case $p$ for $p$-values (and I find it more prevalent in the current literature too), even though I don't really know why.

Comment: No upvote explained is better than a downvote unexplained! I suspect $p$-value is more common. Personal puzzles over notation include why is there is no good agreed notation for medians and why people prefer notations such as $I(a > b)$ or $1_{a > b}$ to a convention that $(a > b)$ is treated as 1 or 0 according to whether a statement is true or false (as in many programming languages). Hat-tip to Kenneth Iverson and Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to use any notation you want $p(X=x)$, $P(X=x)$, $\mathrm{P}(X=x)$, $\Pr(X=x)$ etc. I never heard about any formal rules about it. I have an *impression* that $p(X)$ is more often used when authors want to talk about probability in general and use catchall term for things like probabilities of events $p(X=x)$, probability density functions $p(x)$ etc., while uppercase $P$ or $\Pr$ is used more commonly when talking about events.